# Python Lambda groupby to function and Stop Iteration

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I wrote a function that I am able to successfully use like this:

```
createdata(df)
```

The results are correct. For example the output includes 1 result row for each row in the data frame as expected and the calculations are correct. My problem is that due to memory limitations I cannot run the entire data frame through the function at the same time so I have to send the data frame through the function iteratively.

I cannot send the data frame to the function row by row because there is a rank by group aspect to the algorithm. So I have to send at least one group of data at a time to the function. I tried groupby.apply but there were unexpected results due to the apply calling the function twice on the first group. So now I am using a lambda like this.

```
df.groupby(["x", "y"]).apply(lambda x: createdata(df))
```

with this I am getting correct calculations but I am getting 4 identical rows of output for each input row. I am also getting the  Stop Iteration exception when it finishes.

Without getting into the details of the function is there something that I can correct in my approach to simply iterate my function on one group of my data frame at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know zilch about Pandas, but from a quick glance at your code and at the doc, I think you want to pass `x` to `createdata`, not `df` :

```
 df.groupby(["x", "y"]).apply(lambda x: createdata(x))
```

Also, note that according to the doc:

> In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first
>   group to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can
>   lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they will
>   take effect twice for the first group.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/groupby.html#flexible-apply